# How to merge two rows and form new columns?

Tags: r

I want to merge two rows in my dataset and create new columns according to the requirement.

Here's the dataset:

[image]

I want to merge the two rows of same **area_name** and **date_reported** and form some new columns for new_cases and old_cases.

```
library(dplyr)

df %>% group_by(area_name, date_reported) %>% summarise(date_reported =  date_reported, 
area_name = area_name, area_code = area_code, newcase= , oldcase= )

View(df)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would want to `pivot_wider`:

```r
library(tidyr)

df |> 
  pivot_wider(c(date_reported, area_name, area_code), names_from = "metric")
```

**Output:**

```r
# A tibble: 2 × 5
  date_reported area_name area_code new_cases cum_cases
          <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl>
1             1         1         1        37      1685
2             2         2         2        45     11044
```

**Toy data:**

```r
df <- tibble(date_reported = c(1,1,2,2),
             area_name = c(1,1,2,2),
             area_code = c(1,1,2,2),
             metric = rep(c("new_cases", "cum_cases"), 2),
             value = c(37, 1685, 45, 11044))
```